# Word Breaks in middle of sentence - Material UI

Tags: html, css, text, material-ui, styling

I'm currently having an issue with my sentences breaking in the middle. I'm currently using Material UI and I need to work with manually styling the different `MUI` components. Below is an example of the issue I'm having. My best stab was removing the `display: flex` but that caused my icon (or square in below example) to stop floating to the right, which is what I want to keep. How can I fix the text issue along with keeping the square to the right?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  word-break: break-word;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px dotted blue;
  width: 25em;
}

.special {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.square{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This sentence is supposed to display a 
  <span class="special">   special</span>
  styled piece of text.
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: This is my Desired Result

```css
.container2{
   border: 4px dotted blue;
   width: 20em;
}
    
.square2{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:red;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='container2'>
    This sentence is supposed to display a <b>styled </b>piece of text. <div class='square2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking to prevent text from breaking (keeping it on one line)?

Comment: Yep! My desired goal is to have a standard looking sentence "This sentence is supposed to display a styled piece of text" and so the sentence also properly breaks at the end of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: is this the answer you are looking for ?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  word-break: break-word;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px dotted blue;
  width: 25em;
}

.container .text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0
}

.special {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.square{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p class='text'>
    This sentence is supposed to display a 
    <span class='special'>   special</span>
    styled piece of text.
  </p>
  <div class='square'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost! But the square should be floating to the right

Answer (score 1):

Flex is causing the text to be split into multiple blocks, because it is treating the text either side of `.special`, and the element itself as separate children.

Wrapping the sentence in a `<span>` causes flexbox to treat it as a single element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  word-break: break-word;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px dotted blue;
  width: 25em;
}

.special {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.square{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>This sentence is supposed to display a <span class="special">special</span> styled piece of text.</span>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the text in another div and keep your flex on the container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  word-break: break-word;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px dotted blue;
  width: 25em;
}

.special {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.square{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
      This sentence is supposed to display a <span class="special">special</span> styled piece of text.
    </div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I currently have the restriction with Material UI that I can't wrap the text in a div. Is there a workaround for this?